# Ignoring Memo fields with simpledbf

Tags: python, dbf

I have dBASE Plus 2.6 file, which I am trying to convert to Pandas dataframe.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5

db = Dbf5('file.dbf')
print(db)
df = db.to_dataframe()
```

Executing this code gives following output:

```
<simpledbf.simpledbf.Dbf5 object at 0x0000013BE4F5B860>
File "C:/.../Main.py", line 7, in <module>
df = db.to_dataframe()
File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\simpledbf\simpledbf.py", line 316, in to_dataframe
results = list(self._get_recs())
File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\simpledbf\simpledbf.py", line 660, in _get_recs
raise ValueError(err.format(value))
ValueError: Column type "b'          '" not yet supported.
```

This error is caused by one of the fields having memo ('M') type.
Is there any way to ignore these fields while converting to a dataframe or delete these fields before running the to_dataframe() method?

Comment: Hmm, what gives `print(db.fields)`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - One of the fields has 'M' type (Memo?), which is not supported by simpledbf and seems to be causing the problem.

Is there any way to delete this field before converting to dataframe?

Comment: Author says that simpledbf does not support memo fields. So I would try to use another package like [dbfread](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [dbf](https://pypi.org/project/dbf) to remove it. Disclaimer I have never used any ot them...